# NotifyDataSetChanged not called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged, android-adapterview

I am trying to make an app with card swipe like tinder. I have a Texview with some text on it and when I swipe next card has another text and so on. What I also want to do is when i click on a button to remove the card on screen and go to the next one. I am removing first String from a list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChange. The problem is that the text on screen stays the same even tough the string is removed every time I click. I even Loged the values in adapter and they are changed and number of cards are dropping but the text on the screen stays the same.

When I download data in onResponse I call, flingContainer is custom view that extends adapterView

```
myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(list, this);
flingContainer.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
```

When I click the button I call

```
list.remove(0);
myAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is my adapter

```
public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<String> parkingList;
    public Context context;

    private MyAppAdapter(List<String> apps, Context context) {
        this.parkingList = apps;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            ViewHolder.background = (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.background);
            viewHolder.cardImage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.cardImage.setText(parkingList.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `list.remove(0)` so it's just remove first index from your list not from your *Adapter*. In fact you pass copy of list into your *Adapter* and they're different; So to make it work In addition to call list.remove(0) add `removeItem()` in your adapter:

```
public void removeItem(int index){
      parkingList.remove(index);
      notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

Comment: I tried that one too but it didnt work for me as well as many other things, but after some time what I found that worked for me was `removeAllViewsInLayout()` before `notifyDataSetChange()` . But I still dont know why this didnt work.

Comment: You should call both removeItem(index) & list.remove() did you?

Comment: double check your instance. removeAllViewsInLayout is not recommend at all in this case.

Comment: Also instead of getInflater use LayoutInflater.from()

Comment: Yes I did remove it in adapter too, the values in adapter where fine and even click on the card returned the right value but the textview always showed the old value

Comment: @tinoba provide more information ( your viewHolder class or xml). your code is just fine.